# DVWA unable to connect to database using MAMP

Tags: mac, mamp

I have installed Dam Vulnerable Web Application (DVWA) on my mac using MAMP.
This is my config file setting:

```
$_DVWA = array();

$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = '127.0.0.1';

$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';

$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';

$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';
```

I get the error 'unable to connect to database' when I load DVWA on my browser as shown in pic.

I have looked on this forum and by setting password to blank it appears to fix the problem for xampp, but its not worked for mamp.

The url I browse to using MAMP is: localhost:8888/dvwa

Any idea where Im going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. These are the config settings required for MAMP:

```
$_DVWA = array();
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = 'localhost';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'root';
```